# Debugging MAUI app on Android after manual launch

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022, maui

I have a MAUI app on Android which works perfectly when launched from Visual Studio with the debugger attached. If I published an APK and install it on the device manually, the application crashes as soon as I use the AppShell to change the current page.

How can I attach the debugger to it after I've launched it manually? Failing that, just finding a way to see a stack trace for the unhandled exception would be a big step forward.

I tried capturing a bug report and reproducing the crash, but the report did not appear to contain any account of crash. I was unable to find any crash dump logged by the OS, but this is my first Android app, so I might be missing something there.

Comment: Have you tried using `adb logcat` to see device logs? Maybe the error will be reported there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jan-joneš, you set me along the right path. Although it's outdated with respect to MAUI, I found a [useful page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows) in the Xamarin documentation with more tips.

It would be so much easier if these exceptions were flagged by the debugger!